# pod cannot be installed

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I have problem with running app on ios that was cloned from github i tried to install pod put it giving me this error.

[!] Error installing MaterialControls
[!] /usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/fpt-software/Material-Controls-For-iOS.git /var/folders/0s/r4qtkcpj5wsbp5qrn3x224x00000gn/T/d20200819-21909-1j0u8aj --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch v1.2.2

Cloning into '/var/folders/0s/r4qtkcpj5wsbp5qrn3x224x00000gn/T/d20200819-21909-1j0u8aj'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/fpt-software/Material-Controls-For-iOS.git/' not found

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to run `pod install` inside your IOS folder

Comment: actually the problem happening when I do this

Answer (score 0):

This project does not exist anymore, so that's the probleme. You can try to open a new project and copy the dart files, if you still have them.

Comment: what errors do you get? if files are missing you sadly won't get it to work. But if you are looking for iOS styled widgets, dart already has you covered anyway: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/cupertino

Comment: the whole problem one of the depndency got delited from github, called MaterialControls.